# Calculate road distance between two points in PostGIS - Resultant distance is not accurate (not even close to the actual distance)

Tags: postgis, distance, route

```
SELECT
torigin1.id AS origin_id,
tdest1.id AS destination_id,
CASE
    WHEN ST_LineLocatePoint(troad.line_string, torigin1.geom) < ST_LineLocatePoint(troad.line_string, tdest1.geom)
    THEN ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(troad.line_string, 
        ST_LineLocatePoint(troad.line_string, torigin1.geom), 
        ST_LineLocatePoint(troad.line_string, tdest1.geom)
    ))
    ELSE ST_Length(ST_LineSubstring(troad.line_string, 
        ST_LineLocatePoint(troad.line_string, tdest1.geom), 
        ST_LineLocatePoint(troad.line_string, torigin1.geom)
    ))
END AS road_distance
FROM troad
INNER JOIN torigin1 ON troad.gid = torigin1.gid
INNER JOIN tdest1 ON troad.gid = tdest1.gid
WHERE torigin1.gid IN (2) AND tdest1.gid IN (2);
```

The result I got is not close to the actual distance. All three datasets used are in UTM projection 32644 as the region I worked is in India.

I have tried using **ST_ClosestPoint** as well but still the answer is not correct.

Comment: "Not close" is not descriptive. What is the actual value? What was computed? What data values would reproduce the behavior?

Comment: joining the road segments and origin/dest by ID seems counterintuitive, especially since you then fetch a geometry which may or may not be near the associated segment. Also it may work only if a single road segment is retrieved (by id)

Comment: You mention "road distance". Do you mean the distance via the road network? If so, this is a job for pgrouting, but your table troad needs to be in a particular format (columns: id, source, target, cost, where source and target are the ids of the nodes at each end).

Answer (score 3):

A more versatile, more performant approach:

```
SELECT
  ori.id AS origin_id,
  dst.id AS destination_id,
  ST_Length(tr.line_string) * ABS(dst.frac - ori.frac) AS road_distance
FROM
  troad AS tr
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      o1.id,
      ST_LineLocatePoint(tr.line_string, o1.geom) AS frac
    FROM
      torigin1 AS o1
    WHERE
      o1.gid = tr.gid
  ) AS ori
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      d1.id,
      ST_LineLocatePoint(tr.line_string, d1.geom) AS frac
    FROM
      tdest1 AS d1
    WHERE
      d1.gid = tr.gid
  ) AS dst
WHERE
  tr.gid IN (2)
;
```

For each row in `troads` we find the fractions of line length of the projections of both `ori.geom` & `dst.geom` (having the same `gid`) onto the inital *LineStrings*.

We then simply take the (absolute) difference between both fractions and apply this to the length of the respective initial *LineString*.

---

Note that this can only ever work correctly if all `troad.line_string` geometries are *single, simple LineStrings*, and there is exactly *one pair of `torigin1` & `tdest1` rows per `troads` row*! If that is not the case, and there are multiple pairs per road, you would want to *loop over the point tables instead*, executing the same calculations.

If these distances are then still not correct I would assume there's a projection issue, or the geometries are not suitable.

Comment: Geozelot, you should write a PostGIS book, your answers are grand, thank you!

Comment: @TimothyDalton that is a very nice thing to hear, much appreciated! You would so much not want to read a book I wrote, though...